# Task <E94BEE4D-E88B-4827-BE0A-E5CF1FE35F5C>.<0> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1200 [3:-9858])

Tags: ios, objective-c, https, nsurlconnection

I am using the functionality of upload images in my application. Application sends the images to server using SOAP request. Recently I made the urls from http to https and I am facing this problem,

Task .<0> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1200 [3:-9858])

NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1200

I have tried all changes in info.plist yet it is not working. Could you please help me?
Thank you

Comment: Are you 100% sure the certificate is valid? Can you access the server using your browser or postman no problem or do you get a warning?

Comment: Yes certificate is valid, it works for android application with same certificate. Yes I can access the server using browser, I didn't get any warning there. Is there any need of certificate pinning or public key pinning in application?

Comment: You'll have to show the code ...

Comment: I have uploaded the code please check

Comment: Hi - I see you have a ? in the URL. You need to remove that also!

Comment: Yes I removed it. Is there any need of certificate pinning or public key pinning in application?

Comment: Not 100% sure but I dont think you need pinning. After the question mark and adding that ```else``` is it still not working?

Comment: Yes I followed all steps that you have provided but its still not working. sometimes its showing images in collection view, sometimes not.

Comment: Then actually I think this is working ... problem maybe on the collection view side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, look at this ...

```
if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod  
isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])      
[challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential    
credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] 
forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

[challenge.sender   
continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
```

I *think* it should be

```
if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod  
isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])      
[challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential    
credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] 
forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
else // you need to add an else here
[challenge.sender   
continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
```

**EDIT**

Also, I see you give the URL as

```
https://pro-ap.com.au/Mobile/profilepic.asmx?
```

Remove the last question mark as that is part of the request and will be appended automatically as the request is built.

Comment: No problem yes the formatting here can be difficult ... I've taken out that comment ...